# Android KeyStore, Eclipse -> Android Studio

Tags: android, keystore

I am stuck in a problem. 
I developed an Android app back in 2014, and now I am updated it. 
I imported the project in Android Studio and it worked just fine.
But after development when I am trying to sign the app, it just kept saying password is incorrect or keystore has been tampered with.

In eclipse I had only one password but in Android I've enter two passwords and one alias.

None of the helps worked that are on stackoverflow.

There could be two solutions to this problem.

- A way of importing Android Studio gradle project in Eclipse and signing apk.
- How to sign apk with only 1 password?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sign your apk with only one password. Every keystore have three parameters: an alias (some times you can use the same name of the keystore, try..), an alias password and a store password (the password can be the same, for alias and store, there are no controls about it).

Comment: You cannot have a simple solution: IMHO you can try to retrieve your password(s) and alias changing it with java keytool. By command line you can try to know if your password is the alias or the store one, and if alias can be the same name of the keystore. If you are lucky, you can easly retrive all informations! Make a copy of it, first of all! I have had the same issue, but the keystore wasn't mine, and the only thing to do is to make another one keystore, and backup ALL informations first!

Comment: Have you ever made a script to compile your app in 2014?